# ListLogPlot ignores FrameTicks specification

Tags: plotting, bugs, ticks, frame

**Bug existing in 10.4.1, fixed in 11+**

---

I have a data set

```
nComps = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
memory = {76080, 517176, 12750888, 78101640, 1880868104};
data = MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {nComps, memory}];
```

that I am trying to plot using `ListLogPlot`. I have other plots that all utilize the same format, but when I try to specify those same tick specifications in `ListLogPlot`, Mathematica does not follow the input for the left part of the frame. Here is my tick specification (**edited to add lengths and thicknesses**):

```
tickLength = .03;
tickLengthMinor = .01;
majorTickThickness = Large;
minorTickThickness = Medium;

yTicksMajor = 
  Table[{N[10^i], Superscript[10, i], {tickLength, 0}, 
    Thickness[majorTickThickness]}, {i, 4, 10}];
yTicksMinor = 
  Table[{N[j*10^i], "", {tickLengthMinor, 0}, 
    Thickness[minorTickThickness]}, {i, 4, 10}, {j, 2, 9, 2}];
yTicksTotal = 
  Flatten[Table[
    Join[{yTicksMajor[[i]]}, yTicksMinor[[i]]], {i, 1, 
     Length@yTicksMajor}], 1];

xTicksMajor = 
  Table[{i, i, {tickLength, 0}, Thickness[majorTickThickness]}, {i, 0,
     10}];
xTicksMinor = 
  Table[{i + j, "", {tickLengthMinor, 0}, 
    Thickness[minorTickThickness]}, {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0.2, 1, 0.2}];
xTicksTotal = 
  Flatten[Table[
    Join[{xTicksMajor[[i]]}, xTicksMinor[[i]]], {i, 1, 
     Length@xTicksMajor}], 1];
```

and when I plot using this function

```
ListLogPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{yTicksTotal, None}, {xTicksTotal, None}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

I get

[image: plot]

I can enter a simple list as my tick specification, i.e.

```
yTicksTotal = Table[10^i, {i, 5, 10}]
```

and it will put the specified ticks on the frame, but as soon as I begin specifying a display value, length, or thickness it plots the exact same thing as what I showed in the figure. Does anybody see an error here? I have successfully changed the ticks in `ListPlot`, `Plot`, and `LogLogPlot`, but can't find the solution for `ListLogPlot`.

Comment: What Mathematica version are you using?

Comment: @CarlWoll 10.4 on Windows

Comment: The tick lengths and thicknesses are undefined, could you provide them as well? But, I don't see what you observe in either 10.3.1 or 11.1. Could you provide the InputForm of the graphic?

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes sorry, I just edited the post.

Comment: I can reproduce this in 10.4.1 on Windows, but it looks to have been resolved in 11+. Is upgrading an option for you?

Comment: @user6014 Yes I believe so, but I am hesitant to upgrade at this stage in the project. It appears that I may not have an option if I want to use `ListLogPlot`, though.

Comment: @haff From personal experience I have found that 11.2 tends to be pretty stable, and particularly in this area (`*LogPlot` stuff) many issues have been resolved. I would personally recommend upgrading, although that's based on my workflow and what I use, and you may differ :)

Comment: This also works fine in 10.2 on Windows so it must have been introduced as a bug in either 10.3 or 10.4. One other option is to use "Show Expression" by pressing Ctrl-Shift-E on the output cell to see if you can identify the problem and fix it manually.

Comment: I upgraded to version 11.2 and my entire project code works fine. Looks like that was the easiest fix.